# Wait for multiple Alamofire requests to complete before continuing?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uikit, alamofire

I'm loading a bunch of files through Alamofire requests. I want to show a "loading…" spinner (MBProgressHUD) while they load.

But I'm having some trouble determining when all the requests have finished, so that I can hide the HUD at the correct time!

So far, everything I've tried has resulted in the hud being hidden too early, or never at all. Currently, I have my requests wrapped in an NSOperation subclass, with a simple NSBlockOperation to hide the hud, which has all the Alamofire request operations as dependencies. But I can't figure out how to get the requests to be marked as finished at the right time.

Ideally I'd like to find a solution that's simpler than this. What would be the best way to accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `disptach_group_t` Here is Example

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

__weak MainViewControllerSupplier * weakSelf = self;
dispatch_group_enter(group);
[self showHUD];
[[DataManager sharedManager] getCategoriesWithSuccessBlock:^(NSArray *categories) {
    weakSelf.arrCategories = categories;
    dispatch_group_leave(group);

   // NSLog(@"response  category= %@",categories);
} failureBlock:^(NSError  *error) {
    NSLog(@"response category = %@",error);
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
}];

dispatch_group_enter(group);
[[DataManager sharedManager] getRegionsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSArray *regions) {
    weakSelf.arrRegions = regions;
    dispatch_group_leave(group);
} failureBlock:^(id error) {
    NSLog(@"response region = %@",error);
    dispatch_group_leave(group);

}];

dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self hideHUD];
    });
  // All task completed 

});
```